# JAVA_HOME & JAVA_OPTS set in catalina.sh but 'printenv' in bash/python doesn't show those environment variables

Tags: java, python-3.x, bash, tomcat, environment-variables

I am rather new to java and tomcat and wanted to see if I could get yalls help in an understanding of what's happening.

I am noticing in our tomcats catalina.sh file, the following env vars are set:

export JAVA_HOME="/home/aim111prod/jdk-11.0.7+10"

export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms8192m -Xmx8192m -Drhino.opt.level=0 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dcom.aw.aim.bootstrap.file=/home/aim111prod/conf/Catalina/bootstrap.xml -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US"

Tomcat is running, but when I run 'printenv' these 2 env vars do not appear in 'printenv' results.

I am hoping to eventually write a simple start/stop/restart script using python3.

I am assuming because 'printenv' is not showing the 2 set java options in catalina.sh that os.environ.get() wouldn't work either.

What I am noticing is that when 'printenv' is used,
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre

I suppose I am needing some help in understanding the way the 2 environment variables are being used?

How would I reference the 2 env vars set in catalina.sh with python if 'printenv' isn't picking them up?

Please take it easy on me lol I am not as smart as some of you all, but I am trying!

Thank you for your help / time/ suggestions.

--
bash-brain

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're expecting catalina.sh to set those environment variables, and have the changes take effect system-wide.  But environment variables don't work like that; `export` changes the environment of the current process and any child processes.
It doesn't affect any parent processes, or unrelated processes on the system.

One solution is to write a wrapper shell script that **sources** catalina.sh (to set up the environment variables in the process that's running your wrapper script), then calls python.  The python program would then be able to see the correct set of environment variables.  Note:  you would have to use a command like `source catalina.sh` or `. catalina.sh` to run the commands in catalina.sh in the current process.  If you simply execute `catalina.sh` as a standalone command, it will run in a new process, set the variables there, and exit the process without propagating the variables back to the parent process (i.e. your wrapper script).